# Changing column datatype with QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis

[image]I have seen a solution that I don't get to work - I need to change data type from string to integer and I did what is shown i the image below
Can someone point out what I do wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can update a field using itself. Create  new field, as type integer, with the expression you used, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Install the "table manager" plugin.

Create a new field (via the checkboxes atop the field calculator window) with the correkt data type.

Use table manager (from vector menu) to reoder fields as needed.

Comment: Ok! I see - I was under the impression that I actually could change the data type for a field. Thx /Jan

Answer (score 1):

In Qgis 2.18.10 you can do this without a plugin:

[image]

afterwards you can delete the "original" column - BBL in this case - and rename INTBBL to BBL:
[image]